# Reading csv-file in Python containing undefined characters

Tags: python, csv, text, utf-8, ascii

I am reading a CSV-file (ANSI) on my Windows-machine in Python using this code:

```
import csv
with open('ttest.dat') as csvDataFile:
    csvReader = csv.reader(csvDataFile, delimiter="\t")
    for i in csvReader:
        print(i)
```

However, I get the error: `UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x9d in position 4: character maps to <undefined>`

Upon inspecting the file in Notepad++ (after converting it to UTF-8 encoding in Notepad) I see that the following appears:

[image]

It seems that these characters adjacent to `hello` are causing the issue. When I remove them manually the file can be read.

Is there a way to load the file in Python while explicitly telling it to disregard these odd characters? Or, alternatively, is there a method  to strip the text from these characters automatically? My file is rather large, so it isn't realistic that I manually look through each line.

Note: In R I can read the file without any issues using `read.csv`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with open('ttest.dat', encoding="utf8") as csvDataFile:
```

This will open the file with UTF-8 encoding.

Comment: This circumvents the issue with the odd characters, but now I can't parse text that contains letters æ, ø and å

Comment: Is that Norwegian letters? Try `iso-8859-1`. Otherwise look up some some tutorials on the subject. You will definitely find something that will help.